# python: module not found (despite module included in sys.path)

Tags: python, module, sys.path

I have a python script that is calling a module from another python project, whose path is correctly included in sys.path, however the script returns error "module not found".

More in detail, this is the following structure:

/home/lbri/sdfstudio/script.py --> the main script that I am running

/home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/data/transforms.py --> the module that I am trying to call from script.py

These are the relevant lines inside script.py:

```
sys.path.append(args.omnidata_path)
print(sys.path)
from data.transforms import get_transform
```

which is run with

```
python script.py --omnidata-path /home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/
```

This is the error that I get:

```
['/home/lbri/sdfstudio/scripts/datasets', '/home/lbri/miniconda3/envs/sdfstudio/lib/python38.zip', '/home/lbri/miniconda3/envs/sdfstudio/lib/python3.8', '/home/lbri/miniconda3/envs/sdfstudio/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/lbri/miniconda3/envs/sdfstudio/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '__editable__.nerfstudio-0.1.12.finder.__path_hook__', '/home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 41, in <module>
    from data.transforms import get_transform
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data.transforms'
```

I don't understand: the path of the module ('/home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/') is included correctly in sys.path, yet the script does not see the module. Am I missing something obvious?

I also tried to put some **init**.py files inside the folders containing the module, but nothing changes.

Thank you!

EDIT: I also tried to include /home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/data/ into the sys.path as well, but I still get the same error.

Comment: It appears that `torch` is definitely in path, but I don't see `data` anywhere in that path. `data` what? `data` where? Every directory on your entire file system could have a data directory in it - python expects you to be more specific. Maybe you meant `torch.data.transforms` or possibly `.data.transforms`?

Comment: I tried to run the script with --omnidata-path /home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/data/ as well, but the error remains.

Comment: basically, I tried to include in sys.path both omnidata_tools/torch and omnidata_tools/torch/data, but the error is still there

Comment: Just change your import to the proper import. Why are you trying to confuse python into working instead of just doing it right?

Comment: @OneMadGypsy sorry I don't understand your last comment, can you please elaborate better? and yes, the 'data' folder has a __init__ py file inside it

Comment: "It appears that torch is definitely in path, but I don't see data anywhere in that path. data what? data where?". Here: /home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/ __data__ /transforms.py

Comment: @DallogFheir ~ You're just making things up. That's not in the OP's system path, at all. We're talking about what is ACTUALLY in the system path, not what MAY be in the system path under various conditions.  `['/home/lbri/sdfstudio/scripts/datasets', '/home/lbri/miniconda3/envs/sdfstudio/lib/python38.zip', '/home/lbri/miniconda3/envs/sdfstudio/lib/python3.8', '/home/lbri/miniconda3/envs/sdfstudio/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/lbri/miniconda3/envs/sdfstudio/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '__editable__.nerfstudio-0.1.12.finder.__path_hook__', '/home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/']`

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I tried to add /home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/data/ as well to sys.path, it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Damian I don't understand why you don't just import it the expected way and quit trying to skip the `torch` reference.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy under what conditions? `data` is clearly inside `torch`. And `.data.transforms` would tell Python to search for `data` in the current package, and `torch.data.transforms` to search for `torch`, but that's just a folder already added in PYTHONPATH.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy Can you please explain what do you mean by "why you don't just import it the expected way"? sorry but I am confused.

Comment: @Damian - No. My first comment already touched on this. I'm done with this question.

Comment: @Damian so do you have \_\_init\_\_.py file in `data`?

Comment: @DallogFheir - If you say so. That's an awful lot of "clearly" for something that doesn't work.

Comment: @DallogFheir yes, there is a __ init __. py file inside data folder.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I tried already what you said (adding data to the syspath), but as I said, it doesn't work.

Comment: @DallogFheir I just found out the reason of the issue, let me add an answer to explain it.

Comment: @Damian ok, I'm curious, because it works on my end. By the way, is there any reason you're using Python 2? On Python 3 it should work even without \_\_init\_\_.py.

Comment: Or Python3.3 to be precise, because that's where namespace packages were introduced.

Comment: I didn't say anything about adding anything to path. I simply said it isn't there. I said to do this `from torch.data.transforms import get_transform`. You put `torch` in syspath - so refer to it!

Comment: basically it works if I add '/home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools' in the syspath, and then I change the include to: from omnidata_tools.torch.data.transforms import get_transform. ---------- however it does *not* work if I add '/home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch' in the path and I change the include to: from torch.data.transforms import get_transform. I think the reason is that torch is already imported as another module, so this confuses python (same explanation for 'data'). I think this is what @OneMadGypsy was trying to say, although I could't understand it.

Comment: @DallogFheir - Are you in this universe or crossing over? First you tell me paths are there that are clearly not there, now you are claiming this is python2, when it clearly is not. From the syspaths alone you can determine this is python 3.8. The `print` call also gives it away.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy I thought you were done with this question?

Comment: "I think this is what @OneMadGypsy was trying to say" - Nope, I can't take any credit for that. You figured that one out on your own. GJ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, posting the answer to my question, with a bit of delay.

Basically the main problem is that 'data' and 'torch' are too generic names - which are already used by the script to indicate different modules.

Therefore, the solution was:

- add `/home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools` in the syspath
- change the include to: `from omnidata_tools.torch.data.transforms import get_transform`

Then everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, you need to make sure that the module data.transforms is actually in the directory /home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/ and that it is a Python module. You can check this by opening the directory in a file explorer and looking for the file data/transforms.py. If the file is not there, or if it is not a Python module, then you will need to create it or install the module

Comment: the file transforms.py is there already.

Answer (score -1):

its trying to import from one folder up

```
sys.path.append(args.omnidata_path)
print(sys.path)
from transforms import get_transform

python script.py --omnidata-path /home/lbri/omnidata/omnidata_tools/torch/data
```

Comment: Tried already, same error.